# What is a quick way to check if a user has a particular role in my Laravel application?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, ioc-container

I'm currently building a web application using Laravel 4 PHP Framework, and part of my app is only visible to subscribers and administrators; and obviously I don't want guests to see these sections of my site.

Each user has a `role_id` which corresponds to a value in an abstract static class in acts as an enum:

```
abstract class UserRole {
    const Unauthenticated = 1;
    const Member = 2;
    const Subscriber = 3;
    const CharterSubscriber = 4;
    const Moderator = 5;
    const Administrator = 6;
}
```

Because a lot of my content is dynamic depending on the role a user has; I'm finding I'm checking if a user is of a particular role or greater using the Blade PHP syntax in my Views.

To do this, I'm having to use a rather verbose syntax:

```
@if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->role_id == UserRole::Administrator)
```

...is a good example. The problem here is I first have to check if Auth::user() exists; if it doesn't, the second logical comparison will fail, so I can't even do this:

```
@if (Auth::user()->role_id == UserRole::Administrator)
```

...which is cleaner, but still pretty verbose. Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
@if (Auth::isAdmin())
```

...or...

```
@if (Auth::isSubscriberOrGreater())
```

**How can I accomplish this?** I don't know that much about Laravel's IOC container, so any answers are going to have to be reasonably well explained.

Comment: You could extend Auth, of course, but wouldn't it be a lot easier (and arguably make more sense) to just put it in the user model? Then you could have `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` etc.

Comment: As previous comment suggests you can just extend the Auth class and add your isAdmin function to it. It will still need the same if test to be done

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a solution, though it might be a little bit ugly:

[Auth::user() method](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html#method_user) returns you the User model or NULL, so in the user model you can check if the user is admin with isAdmin method (or you can perform any other check) like this:

```
public function isAdmin(){ 
     if( $this->role_id == 6){
        return True;
     }
     return False;
}
```

(really you can call method any other name and perform any other check there).
and in then in blade template you'll have something like this:

```
@if (@Auth::isAdmin())
```

To avoid throwing a notice you simply put '@' which is an [Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) in front of the variable.